# What is the difference between Java CPU and PSU Releases, eg JDK SE 8u101 and JDK SE 8u102

Tags: java, jdk, android-studio

I'm installing JDK SE 8u101 on my mac for Android Studio.  Is there any reason I should pick [8u102 vs. 8u101](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)?  Are there any noticeable differences in them? Looks like they were [released at the same time](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8u101_8u102_7u111_and).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Are there any noticeable differences in them?

- 8u101 contains security updates. This is a Critical Patch Update (CPU).
- 8u102 contains the security updates and new features. This is a Patch Set Update (PSU). There is also a known bug in 8u101 which is resolved in 8u102.

Release notes:

- [8u101 Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u101-relnotes-3021761.html)
- [8u102 Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u102-relnotes-3021767.html)

---

#### Java CPU and PSU Releases Explained

**Which Java version should I choose: the CPU or the PSU?**

> Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE users upgrade to the latest CPU release available for a release family. Most users should choose the CPU release.
>
> Users should only use the corresponding PSU release if they are being impacted by one of the additional bugs fixed in that version as noted in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-relnotes-index-2162236.html).
>
> The subsequent CPU release will contain all of the fixes from the current PSU. For this reason, organizations should test the current PSU in their environment in anticipation of these fixes being included in the next CPU.

**What is the difference between a Java CPU and PSU release?**

> Java SE Critical Patch Updates (CPU) contain fixes to security vulnerabilities and critical bug fixes. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE users upgrade to the latest CPU releases as they are made available. Java SE CPU releases are odd numbered versions (i.e. 7u71, 7u65 – see more on Java SE version numbering schemes [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-update-release-numbers-change-1836624.html)).
>
> Java SE Patch Set Updates (PSU) contain all of fixes in the corresponding CPU, as well as additional non-critical fixes. Java PSU releases should only be used if you are being impacted by one of the additional bugs fixed in that version. The release notes call out the additional fixes available in Java SE PSU releases.

Source [Java CPU and PSU Releases Explained](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/cpu-psu-explained-2331472.html)

Comment: So the short answer is: choose 8u102, or in most cases, the highest numbered version.

Comment: @wordsforthewise No, the opposite. If you read the answer carefully Oracle recommends the **lower** numbered version. "Most users should choose the CPU release."

Comment: I see, but it seems like the PSU has fixed a bug in the CPU and has more features, and would be a better choice, right?  I wonder what the bug fix in the PSU is.  Is it this: [When a large TLS (Thread local storage) size is set for Threads, the JVM results in a stack overflow exception.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u102-relnotes-3021767.html) ?


Also, that's annoyingly confusing that they use the acronym 'CPU'.

Comment: @wordsforthewise "JRE 8u101 is not recognized by Internet Explorer (IE) when using static class ID
When a static class id is used to launch an applet or web start application while using JRE 8u101, users will get an unwanted dialogue box stating that they either use the latest JRE or cancel the launch even though they have installed and are using the latest JRE (JRE 8u101)". - "To work around this issue, users can do one of the following two things:
(1) Hit launch with the latest version (8u101) and ignore the warning.
(2) Install JRE 8u102 instead of JRE 8u101 to avoid this issue."

Comment: Ok.  Kind of a silly bug, who uses IE? Haha

Comment: I'm looking at 1.8u161 and u162 and see that 161 has a lot of new features and a bugfix, while 161 only has the same bugfix. Also, neither in the release notes or the download page is any mention of which is CPU or PSU. Did I overlook something?

Comment: @DavidBalažic From my answer "**Java SE CPU releases are odd numbered versions**"

Comment: @DavidPostill I made a typo in my previous comment, the correct text is "161 has a lot of new features and a bugfix, while 162 only has the same bugfix." So the odd version (161) has new features.

Comment: @DavidBalažic Hmm. *shrug*. Looks like Oracle has changed their numbering system then ...